# Flask JWT GraphQL - set access/refresh cookies

Tags: flask, graphql, jwt

set_access_cookies/set_refresh_cookies doesn't save cookies and throws an error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/_compat.py", line 202, in to_bytes raise TypeError("Expected bytes")

GraphQL Error:

```
   {
      "errors": [
       {
       "message": "Expected bytes",
       "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "auth"
      ]
    }
    ],
    "data": {
      "auth": null
     }
    }
```

configurations:

```
app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['cookies']
app.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = False
app.config['JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)
app.config['JWT_COOKIE_SECURE'] = False
app.config['JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = datetime.timedelta(days=15)
app.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = True
app.config['JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_HEADER_NAME'] = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-ACCESS"
app.config['JWT_REFRESH_CSRF_HEADER_NAME'] = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-REFRESH"
```

auth_mutation.py:

```
class AuthMutation(graphene.Mutation):
access_token = graphene.String()
refresh_token = graphene.String()
resp = graphene.String()

class Arguments:
    email = graphene.String(required=True)
    password = graphene.String(required=True)

def mutate(self, info, password, email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    payload = user.uuid

    if user and user.check_password(password):
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=payload),
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=payload)

        resp = jsonify({'Login': True})
        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)

        return AuthMutation(
            access_token=access_token,
            refresh_token=refresh_token,
            resp=resp
        )
    else:
        raise Exception('Authenication Failure : User is not registered')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to encode `access_token` and `refresh_token` before sending it to `set_access_cookies` and `set_refresh_cookies`. Try,

```
set_access_cookies(resp, access_token.encode('utf-8'))
set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token.encode('utf-8'))
```

Assuming you're using python3(from the error trace), access_token and refresh_tokens will be unicode strings, however these functions are expecting a byte string

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes